# Website behaving very strange in safari 5.1.7

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

The following website runs fine in all browsers it seems apart from safari on a mac where it goes absolutely mental and crashes the browser. I have tried removing the google map, transforms from the css and the stellar jquery plugin to see if any of these were causing the issues and it still didn't sort it. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
beta.recklessnewmedia.com
```

Comment: You have 14 HTML errors and 629 CSS errors.

Comment: For ref on errors: check the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.recklessnewmedia.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: This is not the issue. I have fixed the HTML errors bar 1 which is really not an issue. All of the CSS errors are in bootstrap which is very widely used and supported so that is not the issue either

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by a jquery plugin that i was using called bxSlider. I swapped it for an alternative and all the problems went away.